# Процент распознавания русской речи, Для программы вывести процент точности распознавания. C#

Tags: c#, распознавание

С помощью библиотеки sphinx реализована программа по распознаванию русской речи. Фонемы черпаются со словаря с фонемами words.JSGF и собственно словоформ words.dic. Восстал вопрос, как вывести процент распознавания слов?
К примеру после прекращения распознавания, по нажатию на кнопку определялся процент распознавания.
Как принято, везде говорят, что процент распознавания равен 90. Как этого добиться в программе. 
Реализация программы на c#

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен но:

1. Подаешь на вход программе то что собираешься сказать в текстовом
   виде.
2. Произносишь эту заранее заготовленную фразу сравниваешь результат
   распознавания с помощью LCS алгоритма с тем что ранее передал.
3. Получаешь % похожести.

Только так, на мой взгляд, можно получить % распознавания, если библиотека сама нативно не может дать эту информацию.

Еще нашел инфу на офф сайте:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialtuning

Она похоже на то, что я описал.

Comment: Попробую.Спасибо. Если что-то получится или не получится, отпишусь.

Comment: LCS алгоритм. Не совсем понял. Дело в том, что фраза может быть люба. Немного не разобрался в алгоритме. Есть код алгоритма?

Comment: @иванантонюк, Я ссылу добавил. На офф сайте есть описание.

Comment: Но в примере описано в том случае, если это звуковые файлы, модели так сказать. У мня подключен словарь JSpeech Grammar Format (JSGF)

Answer (score 0):

Не удалось "прилепить" команду, которая указана на оф.сайте.
Make sure to add -samprate 8000 to the above command if you are decoding 8kHz files!
The script word-align.pl from Sphinxtrain will report you the exact error rate which you can use to decide if adaptation worked for you.

Смысл в том, что я использую словарь и фонемы, а не статическую модель word-align.pl.